# Turning my html dash menu into php

Tags: javascript, php, html

So here's what I had before:

```
<li><a class="selected0" href="/dbp/dbma.html">Dashboard 0</a></li>
<!--        First dashboard selection            -->
                    <li><a class="select1" href="#" onclick="return false;">Dashboard a</a></li>
                    <div class="db1sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="s1a" href="/dbp/db1/db1-1.html">Db 1</a></li>
                            <li><a id="s1b" href="/dbp/db1/db1-2.html">Db 2</a></li>
                            <li><a id="s1c" href="/dbp/db1/db1-3.html">Db 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
<!--        Second dashboard selection            -->
                    <li><a class="select2" href="#" onclick="return false;">Dashboard b</a></li>
                    <div class="db2sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="s2a" href="/dbp/db2/db2-1.html">Db 4</a></li>
                            <li><a id="s2b" href="/dbp/db2/db2-2.html">Db 5</a></li>
                            <li><a id="s2c" href="/dbp/db2/db2-3.html">Db 6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
<!--        Third dashboard selection            -->
                    <li><a class="select3" href="#" onclick="return false;">Dashboard c</a></li>
                    <div class="db3sub">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="s3a" href="/dbp/db3/db3-1.html">Db 7</a></li>
                            <li><a id="s3b" href="/dbp/db3/db3-1.html">Db 8</a></li>
                            <li><a id="s3c" href="/dbp/db3/db3-1.html">Db 9</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Basically, I had 4 selections on my page. If I click on Dashboard a, 3 selections (Dashboard 1,2,3) would appear. If I clicked it again, it'd disappear. Same goes for Dashboard b, if I clicked it, then Dashboard 4,5,6 would appear, and so forth.

Here's what I've done to change it to php:

```
<li><a class="select0" href="/dbp/dbma.html">Dashboard 0</a></li>

                        <?php
                            $a=1;
                            $x=1;
                            while ($a<4){
                                echo "<li><a class=select$a href=# onclick=return false;>Dashboard $a</a></li>";
                                echo "<div class=db$a sub>";
                                    echo "<ul>";
                                        $t=1;
                                        $s='a';

                                        while ($t<4){
                                            echo "<li><a id=s$a$s href=/dbpages/db$a/db$a-$t.html>Dashboard $x</a></li>";
                                            $t++;
                                            $s++;
                                            $x++;
                                        }
                                    $a++;
                                    echo "</ul>";
                                echo "</div>";

                            }

                        ?>
```

Everything comes up and what not, but whenever I open the page, all of the tabs are already open, and they don't appear/disappear when I click on the main dashboard tabs.

Here's what I think the problem is:

```
echo "<div class=db$a sub>";
```

Before, in the HTML version, I had classes called db1sub, db2sub, db3sub. Whenever I tried to put in class=db$asub, it was recognizing $asub as a variable, not $a. So when I spaced this out, the class was no longer db1sub, db2sub, db3sub. They became db1 sub, db2 sub, db3 sub.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `echo "<div class=db".$a."sub>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate the variable using `{}` characters, like this:

```
echo "<div class=db{$a}sub>";
```

You can also use:

```
echo "<div class=db",$a,"sub>";
```